# Symfony2 disable manytoone if not needed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

is there a way to disable the many to one connection in an formbuilder?

Example:
I want to map an menu entry to either an internal routing, or an external link

So 
to another entity or an string like http://www.google.de

The Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unite\MenuBundle\Entity\unmenurouting", inversedBy="unmenus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unmenurouting_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $unmenurouting;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unite\MenuBundle\Entity\unmenu", inversedBy="unsubmenus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unparentmenu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $unmenu;
```

The Formbuilder

```
->add('unmenu','entity',array(
                'class'    => 'UniteMenuBundle:unmenu' ,
                'property' => 'unname' ,
                'multiple' => false ,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                              ->where('m.unmain = 1')
                              ->andwhere('m.unactive = 1')
                              ;
                }
        ))
```

Now i got an error Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association MyBundle\MenuBundle\Entity\unmenu#unmenurouting

So my direct question - is it possible to null the manytoone connection?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Solution so simple ...

```
public function setunmenurouting(Unite\MenuBundle\Entity\unmenurouting $unmenurouting = NULL)
{
    if($unmenurouting !== NULL)
        $this->unmenurouting = $unmenurouting;
    $this->unmenurouting = NULL;
}
```